# Dynamic Loops for Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, discrete-mathematics, truthtable

I want to create a TruthTable maker. So If I have some n variables I will have 2^n rows. With Each Statement conatining only zeros and ones.

For example, Consider A^B. Possible values of A are [0, 1] and for B also [0, 1]. I want to apply AND for A and B. I don't want to appproach in a routine loop way because, In case Variables are greater than 2, I should hardcode loops for every possibility.

Is there any numpy way for my requirement? I mean to apply an Operation for each elements of two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you-

```py
import numpy as np

# the resulting table need not be square
A = np.array([[0, 1]])
B = np.array([[0, 1, 1]])
# repeat B 'row' times
rows = A.shape[1]
B = np.tile(B, (rows, 1))
# transpose A to columns and perform element wise logical and operation
print A.T & B

print (A.T & B) != 0
```

#### output

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 1 1]]

[[False False False]
 [False  True  True]]
```

ps-I would say that the title of the question doesn't quite capture the essence of your question